# oauth enabled mail checker?

Tags: email, notification, mail-notification, oauth

My institution has recently forced all mail clients to use oauth (namely, xoauth2 for MS Exchange). I use mutt as a mail client, and I've reconfigured it to use it, but I'm missing a piece in my mail workflow: a mail checker/notification program. As far as I can tell, none of the ones available on Ubuntu work with oauth. I've tried Bubblemail, Xfce Mailwatch plugin, and Mailnag. Is anybody aware of a way to make this work?

Thanks!